# Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.docs.storage

Tags: android

My app contains the possibility to specify a file into which certain data is stored and read:

```
public void onClickSetFile(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setType("application/json");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {
    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    Uri uri = null;
    if (resultData != null) {
        uri = resultData.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getMainActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while(true) {
                int i = inputStream.read();
                if(i == -1) break;
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            }
            String content = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
            handleFile(content);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        getMainActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("URI", uri.toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

And this is how i open it again:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
String path = preferences.getString("URI", "");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
InputStream inputStream = App.getInstance().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

It used to work fine. I always specified a file on google drive, so i can use the same file with that app on different devices. But now suddenly i get the error `Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.docs.storage` and have to select the file again almost everytime i start the app on my tablet(which i just updated to Android 12). It seems to work fine on my mobile phone (Android 13). Any ideas why and what to do about that?

Comment: editor.putString("URI," AND getString("TAGS_URI" do not match.

Comment: sorry, made a mistake when extracting the relevant part of the code. But i definetely retrieve the saved uri

Comment: The posted code will not produce that error.